# HTML Select - option with text readed from resx file

Tags: html, .net, c#-4.0, resx, culture

i'm working on a project where i'm using culture.
Usually i use this syntax to read text from resx files for my html object:

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" value="" initialvalue="" runat="server"
meta:resourcekey="fCliente" id="myId" class="initial-value" />
```

And this is my resx elements:

```
myId.initialvalue   ValueToBeSetted 
myId.value  ValueToBeSetted
```

This syntax works perfectly.

But i'm not able to do samething for a select element.
In my scenario i've a select element where the user can choose his gender, so it could be like this:

```
<select autocomplete="off" class="initial-value" runat="server" id="fSesso">
<option value="M">Male</option>
<option value="F">Female</option>
<option value="N">Not selected</option>
</select>
```

But text like "Male" or "Female" should be readed from my .resx file.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is a blind guess:

```
<select autocomplete="off" class="initial-value" runat="server" id="fSesso">
<option value="M" meta:resourcekey="Male">Male</option>
<option value="F" meta:resourcekey="Female">Female</option>
<option value="N" meta:resourcekey="Not">Not selected</option>
</select>
```

resx:

```
Male.Text = Male
```

Comment: Unfortunally your soulution doesn't work for select element, but it's works perfectly with an asp DropDownList, so i've replaced it with a DropDown.

Comment: That is funny or not so funny... But glad you found a workaround.

Comment: doesn't work.
If you type <option text="asd"></> it won't display anything

Comment: Yeah, as MassiCiaoCiao pointed out, it only works with the ASP.NET Dropdown. The HTML Element itself does not have the text property.